# submit angularjs form from controller with parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using this form to do search fucntion

```
<form  id="searchForm" name="searchForm" class="form-inline" ng-submit="ul.callServer(criteria)" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                       <label class="searchFormLabel" for="searchUserName">User Name</label>
                      <input type= "text" ng-model = "criteria.userName"/>
                       <label class="searchFormLabel" for="searchUserName">First Name</label>
                      <input type= "text" ng-model = "criteria.firstName"/>
                       <label class="searchFormLabel" for="searchUserName">Last Name</label>
                      <input type= "text" ng-model = "criteria.lastName"/>
                    </div>


    <!---------------------------------------------------users----------------------------------------------------->
                    <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 5px;" ng-init="criteria.userType='-1'">
                        <label class="searchFormLabel" id="searchUser" for="searchUser">
                            User Type
                        </label>
                          <label style="margin-left: 0px">
                              <input type="radio" 
                                     name="userTypeRadioOptions" 
                                     id="searchAll" 
                                     value="-1" 
                                     ng-init="initForm()"
                                     ng-model="criteria.userType"
                                     ng-click="clickAllOrdersButton()">
                              All
                          </label>
                          <br>
                          <label style="margin-left: 124px">
                              <input type="radio" 
                                     name="periodRadioOptions" 
                                     id="searchPending" 
                                     value="0" 
                                     ng-init="initForm()"
                                     ng-model="criteria.userType">
                              Back Office
                          </label>
                          <br>
                          <label style="margin-left: 124px">
                              <input type="radio" 
                                     name="periodRadioOptions" 
                                     id="searchFinished" 
                                     value="1" 
                                     ng-init="initForm()"
                                     ng-model="criteria.userType">
                              Mobiele
                          </label>
                           <br>
                          <label style="margin-left: 124px">
                              <input type="radio" 
                                     name="periodRadioOptions" 
                                     id="searchFinished" 
                                     value="2" 
                                     ng-init="initForm()"
                                     ng-model="criteria.userType">
                              Klanten
                          </label>      
                    </div>
```

when press on button "search" I call the function ul.callServer(criteria)

as you can see I can filter by row type
and this is the scenario I need to implement

- user search for rows with specific type (done)
- user edit the row and change the row type (done)
- I want to refresh the displayed rows with the selected search fields value (not done)

what I want is to call the function ul.callServer(criteria) from controller when I finish the edit operation

if it is not clear please tell me and I will explain more

example:
- I search for rows with type "X" so 3 rows are displayed
- I edit one row and change the type from "X" to "Y"
- when I press on button save to save my new row values I want to 
  1- update the value of the edited row
  2- (Automatically and without the need to press the button search again) display only the rows with type "X"

Comment: What do you mean by finish the edit operation ? Do you mean when the user leaves the focus of the input fields ?

Comment: I update my post so may be it is clear now

Comment: can't you trigger the function ul.callServer(criteria) on ng-change ?

Comment: ng-change for what, I didn't understand what do you mean exactlly

Comment: sorry I understood that you wanted to save without pressing the button. So I think you need to trigger a search (ul.callServer(criteria)) as soon as your rows are saved

Comment: can you show me an example or give me linke how can I do that please

Comment: When I added  angular.element('#searchForm').trigger('submit'); to my controller after save I get this error  **[$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118041/discussion-between-belal-othman-and-oliv37).

Comment: If you could provide a plnkr you should get some more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution

```
$timeout(function(){
  angular.element('#searchForm').triggerHandler('submit');
});
```